# Specialized Turbo “LO BAT” error with torque loss

Tags: electric-bike, battery, specialized-bikes

My Specialized Turbo has started showing momentary (5 second) “LO BAT” errors on the display, and at the same time the motor switches from torque to a stuttering high drag condition.  This only happens on ‘Turbo’ setting, goes away in ‘Eco’. It occurs repeatedly every few minutes. The main battery State of Charge was 40% when it started, and the frequency seemed to increase as SOC dropped.

I thought LO BAT signified the display battery’s SOC, but that should not be dependent on power output and should not affect motor state. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried changing the display battery?

Comment: Battery voltage drops under load. This can be an issue especially at lower charging levels, at low temperature or when a battery is already old and weak.

Comment: One of the cells could be developing a fault that shows under heavier load.

Comment: Change the battery in the TCD (display) and see if the Lo Bat errors disappears. CR2016 batteries are cheap and they surprisingly don’t last that long. I’ve had some last 12 months and others only 6 months.

Comment: I think the ‘cell fault’ theory feels right. Most days on a full charge the SOC only goes to 88%. Mission Control app says the battery is healthy with 115 cycles completed and 500+ to go. 

Wonder what kind of cells they use inside this sucker. Expect Lithium battery refurbishment may become a business with the $1000 price on a replacement!